# How to fix "Failed prop type: The property `spacing` of `grid` must be used on `container`?

Tags: reactjs, grid, material-ui, console.log

I am currently working on a project in which I utilize React and the Material-UI framework. However, after using grid an error pops up saying:

```
checkPropTypes.js:20 Warning: Failed prop type: The property `spacing` of `Grid` must be used on `container`.
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)) (created by NavBar)
    in NavBar (created by Root)
    in Root
```

I have already checked all of my code and the Grid container does use the `spacing` prop.
I have also tried removing spacing from Grid item and this causes more errors.

```
<BrowserRouter>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar style={navStyle}>
          <Grid
            justify="space-between"
            container
            spacing={10}
          >
            <Grid
              item
              spacing={2}
            >
...
```

Everything is showing up on the screen properly, however; this error still pops up. I am unsure how to fix this and would love to learn!

Comment: Looks like the problem is in the NavBar component. You've shown us AppBar and ToolBar.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example e.g. a codesandbox. I would have expected the error to be fixed when you removed the spacing prop from the Grid item in your example.

Answer (score 11):

You can't put spacing prop on an item grid.

Just try to remove the `spacing={2}`

And take a look on the Grid API [MUI](https://material-ui.com/fr/api/grid/)

> spacing : Defines the space between the type item component. It can only be used on a type container component.

Answer (score 6):

There seems to be some confusion about **Grid** that caught me too;

Container

- spacing={number} (number ranging from 0 to 9)

Item

- Usually used within containers
- Sizing similar to Css Grid is provided (xs={12} sm={6} )

**But You can use Item & Container altogether...**

```
<Grid container item xs={12} spacing={3}>
    ....
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `spacing={2}`

To use `spacing` you can try ``containers

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by writing **container** props on my Grid component, I wrote `direction=" column" justifyContent="center" alignItems="center"` on my **Grid** component but getting a warning then I added **container** props it solved but your warning says if you have to add spacing in your **Grid item** component then you have to add **container** on Grid item then it's solved.

Answer (score 0):

All of the above are not necessary. The important thing here is that you only need to ensure the following 3 requirements:
1 : `<Grid container display={'flex'} wrap='wrap'>`
For containers, there is no xs component

2: `<Grid item xs={12} sx={GridMain}>`
For item components, there is no wrap
3 : `<Grid item>` not spacing

---

And in your code, the spacing element should not be used for items. Recommended for use in containers.